# Is it possible to access nuxt context in *.spec.js files?

Tags: typescript, testing, jestjs, nuxt.js

#### Explanation:

I have a ts file, named `repositories.ts` with some HTTP requests in it, this file import into a Nuxt plugin and receives `context.$axios` as an argument.

```js
// ~/repositories.ts

import UserRepository from './repository/user.repository'
import { NuxtAxiosInstance } from '@nuxtjs/axios'

export class RepositoryManager {
  constructor(private axios:NuxtAxiosInstance) {}

  // There are some HTTP requests in this function
  getUser = () => UserRepository(this.axios)
}
```

```js
// ~/plugins/plugin.ts

const repository: Plugin = (context, inject) => {
  inject('repository', new RepositoryManager(context.$axios))
}
```

---

#### What I want to achieve:

Now I want to write a test for one of these HTTP requests in the `repositories.ts`, and I need to pass `context.$axios` to `RepositoryManager()` as an argument but I have 2 below problems right now.

---

#### Problems:

1. I don't know how can I access to **Nuxt context** in `*.spec.js` file, or how to access `context.$axios`
2. When I create a new instance of `RepositoryManager()` in my `*.spec.js` file and run it, I get `TypeError: _repositories.RepositoryManager is not a constructor`